# How to run Java from cmd?

Tags: java, cmd

I have a multithreaded program that imports JSON that I want to run through CMD but right now, I can't because it says its not imported.

How can I fix this problem so that I can always run the program on CMD without additional typing at runtime; i.e., just javac program.java and java program.java

The error is:

```
Client.java:25: error: package com.google.gson does not exist import com.google.gson.Gson;
Client.java:26: error: package com.google.gson.reflect does not exist import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
```

Comment: I know it works because I can run it from eclipse but the problem in this case is that I can't run the same program multiple times in Eclipse

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question & comments, what I am understanding is you are unable to execute your program from command prompt because of external jars.

Please check name of jar where package `com.google.gson` exists & do following

```
javac -cp jar_path.jar Program.java 
java -cp .:jar_path.jar Program
```

If you have multiple such jars then use :

```
javac -cp jar_path.jar;jar1_path.jar Program.java
```

Edit: since it looks like you don't have manifest file, you can put above command in any .bat file & execute that .bat file:

```
@echo off
javac -cp jar_path.jar;jar1_path.jar Program.java
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this so that the external JARs can be run everytime without typing it out in CMD each time?

Comment: Updated answer, have a look & let me know.

Comment: @ArronStarmer _Is there a way to do this so that the external JARs can be run everytime without typing it out in CMD each time?_ - you have fundamental knowledge gaps. If you're not aware of build tools like Ant, Maven or Gradle that do `javac` stuff behind the scenes, making even a tiny batch file including all your Java code dependencies would make your life lot easier (I do bet you'd then move to Ant or `make` just because they are close to batch/script files, and then probably move to Maven for declarative build or Gradle if preferring Groovy scripting).

Comment: @ArronStarmer+ while maven and gradle can do a _lot_ of things for you, to only set the search path for classes for `javac` and `java`, called the classpath, (simply) **set environment variable `CLASSPATH`**. In a given `cmd` process, use `SET CLASSPATH=path1;path2;etc`. To do it for _all_ cmd's you create (1) use `SETX` (do `SETX /?` for help) or (2) start gearicon(settings) and search 'env' (in older days was ControlPanel/System/AdvancedSystemSettings)